# Limit an amount of memory for a third-party javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Is it possible to limit an amount of memory that can be allocated by a third-party javascript code?

**UPDATE:** The ideal situation is to have a 'sandbox' where:

- Some user adds a piece of javascript code.
- This piece of code is being executed.
- If it allocates more than 5 mb - user gets an  exception

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What data? By POST? Uploaded file? Run query?

Comment: @Truth: I mean allocation a huge amount of objects

Comment: This question is so vague that it barely makes sense. Are you writing a browser extension? Do you have a web site and want to control what your visitors can do in other sites? Are you worried about being hacked?

Comment: ok, I will try to explain better with the update to the question itself

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I've tried to explain it better with the update. I hope it is much more clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is depends on browser internal implementation and handled by browser, The end user of browser is not allowed to configure it.